# Параллельная обработка сообщений от пользователей в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, aiogram, асинхронность

Сделал хорошенького бота в телеграме, но вот незадача, он синхронный. Если им будут пользоваться несколько пользователей одновременно, то он сначала выполнит команду одного, потом другого и т.д...

У меня есть хендлер команды start - ничего сложного, просто вывод сообщения.
Есть хендлер на сообщение. Я отправляю в бот сообщение, он его валидирует и запускает определенную функцию. На время работы функции ввод в бота блокируется. Если попытаться ввести новое сообщение, бот просто будет присылать сообщение типа "делаю задачу, как выполню, так пишите". После выполнения функции, можно спокойно отправлять новое сообщение боту.
В случае синхронного бота на Telebot`е, если пользователь 1 отправит сообщение, он запустит выполнение функции, а значит, пользователь 2, при отправке сообщения, получит блокировку в боте - "делаю задачу, как выполню, так пишите". Но сообщение п-ля 2 не встанет в очередь, ему нужно заново писать его.

Я недавно узнал, что Telebot стал поддерживать асинхронность. Я попытался проверить.
В таком случае, выполнение функции встало в очередь. Неважно кто писал в бота - несколько сообщений от п-ля 1 или поочередные от п-ля 1 и п-ля 2. Перестала работать блокировка. А это вообще не то, что мне нужно.

Успешных кейсов море, но я не нашел ни одной подходящей реализации для того, чтобы применить на своем проекте.

А нужно:

1. П-ль 1 и п-ль 2 отправят сообщение в бота, и для каждого из них будет выполняться свой экземпляр функции, то есть параллельно, получая и обрабатывая индивидуальные данные.
2. Блокировка ввода для каждого пользователя должна работать, как в случае синхронности (нельзя отправить сообщение, пока обрабатывается предыдущее).

Код синхронного бота (асинх не сохранял после тестов):

```py
# import`ы

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')
search_in_progress = False

def generate_and_check(code):
    global search_in_progress
    # Блокировка функции на время выполнения
    search_in_progress = True

    path_1 = f"path 1 {code}"
    path_2 = f"path 2 {code}"
    text = f"text + {path_2})"

    # Что-то происходит несущественное...

    try:
        # Работа с path_1 - получаем data_1 и возвращаем вместе с path_1, text:
        return path_1, data_1, text
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        # Если в работе с путями возникли проблемы:
        return path_1, None, text
    finally:
        # Завершаемся и отбой блокировки
        search_in_progress = False

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")

# Обработчик сообщения
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_input(message):
    global search_in_progress
    # Проверка на блокировку и валидация сообщения
    if not search_in_progress and re.match(r'123', message.text):
        # Получаем код из сообщения
        message_code = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ваш код {message_code}")
        # Происходит некоторая проверка...
        # Вызываем generate_and_check, передаем в него message_code и получаем return`ы
        path_1, data_1, text = generate_and_check(message_code)
        
        # Если с путями все ОК
        if path_1 and data_1 is not None:
            result_message = f"ОК - {message_code}\n{data_1} {path_1} {text}"
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result_message)
        # Если с путями все НЕ ОК
        else:
            data_1 = "ВАЩЕ НЕ ОК"
            result_message = f"НЕ ОК - {message_code}\n{data_1} {path_1} {text}"
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result_message)
    # Работа блокировки
    elif search_in_progress:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Занято н....й!")
    # Работа валидации
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Сообщение невалидно")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Код я обезличил, оставил то, с чем можно поработать, остальное к делу не относится.

Вопрос(ы):

1. Можно ли это адекватно поставить на асинхронного Telebot`a, в соответствии с пожеланиями выше? Как?
2. Рассмотрю aoigram3. У меня недостаток опыта работы с асинхронностью, поэтому обрубил синхронным ботом руки себе заранее. Как на нем можно это реализовать?
3. Костыли? На худой конец сойдет...

Comment: в первую очередь я бы наверное отказался от глобальной переменной и использовал иной подход хранение данных, например через sqlite. И да, перешел бы на aiogram3, проблем у вас возникнуть не должно, концепция практически такая же. Вечер за документацией и вы легко перейдете на aiogram. айограм2 ещё больше схож с телеботом.

Comment: @1001001
Пока это мелочи жизни, по сравнению с глобальной проблемой. БД я буду использовать позже. Как мне параллельно то все реализовать?

Comment: использовать aiogram, я же написал. написать две функции которые будут выполнять определенный алгоритм по условию в хендлере. Например один админ другой просто юзер, if(user): func() elif(admin): func(). Асинхроность aiogram'a позволит исполнить ПАРАЛЕЛЬНОЕ использование бота. лол

Comment: по поводу 2го пункта это машины. FSM - aiogram